# How to show Grouped or Bundle Products in my custom template?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, template, layout

I created my own template/skin. Simple products show great but others fail. As far as i know, the following lines in the view.phtml allow me to do this:

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
       <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Those above lines should load the catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml, but they don't in my template. As i ugly workarround i tried implementing the following in my view.phtml:

```
<?php if($_product->isGrouped()) { ?>

                            <?php $this->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
                            <?php $_associatedProducts = $this->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
                            <?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>
                            <table class="data-table grouped-items-table" id="super-product-table">
                                <col />
                                <col />
                                <col width="1" />
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
                                        <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                                        <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                        <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
                                <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
                                    <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_item, $_item->getFinalPrice(), true) ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></td>
                                        <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                                        <td class="a-right">
                                            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml($_item) ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                        <td class="a-center">
                                        <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                                            <input type="text" name="super_group[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>]" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $_item->getQty()*1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                   <tr>
                                       <td colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('No options of this product are available.') ?></td>
                                   </tr>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('super-product-table')</script>

                <?php   } ?>
```

Which is the exact same code as the grouped.phtml but this also fails. Can someone set me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you sure your product options are configured into `container2` and not `container1` ?

Comment: @Tim i forgot to metion that i have the same code als this used for container1 above this one. But still no result.

Comment: Are you using `local.xml` within your theme or are you copying default layout files?

Comment: @Tim i'm using local.xml

Comment: Have you modified anything under `catalog_product_view/content/product.info/product.info.container[1|2]` XPath? do you have any extensions/modifications that overwrite any `mage/catalog` or `mage/template` related classes?

Comment: @Tim not that i know... sort of a beginner in magento templating. Thanks for your reply's BTW. Were getting there.

Comment: This is where proper debugging with breakpoints will help you out a lot to solve the problem.

Comment: sorry, did not finish last comment, and edit time timed out.

This is where proper debugging with breakpoints will help you out a lot to solve the problem.

Get a debugger working in your dev environment, and when functional, you can set a breakpoint on your line

 <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>

at that point you can vie the $this object, and all its properties. You can then easily determine in the child block is in fact available under the _children as a block.

Comment: also, if you drop back down to the core template, does it work?

Comment: @dedmeet yes then it works just fine. I did some debugging statements and i found that `$_hasAssociatedProducts` is false.

Comment: Please write an answer and select it as solution.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt i would if this was the solution? I just said the default template works but not mine.

Comment: damn, didn'T read the whole conversation - sorry :)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt No problem, maybe you can help me solve this issue

Comment: The easiest way is to check the difference between the default template and yours. Or easier: Copy the default template over and then put in the differences step by step. Maybe some js is missing.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If yes, what was the problem?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt nope i'm still searching for an answer :(

Comment: Did you diff your templates against the default ones and check the differences?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I'm so late to the party, but the issue is likely that you are trying to display the grouped product data with the `product.info` block which [by default is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml#L190):

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <!-- ... -->
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
    <!-- ... -->
</catalog_product_view translate="label">
```

That block & template does not display product-type-specific details directly. Rather, the template [echoes the `product_type_data` block](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml#L59):

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
```

The `product_type_data` alias is a perfect example of *why* aliases exist in Magento layouts - it allows blocks to exist in layout (requiring a unique name) yet **still be assigned as children of other blocks without needing to have a separate template for each combination**. Note all of the type-specific handles in *`catalog.xml`* which each specify a type-specific block instance & template, yet all assign these type-specific blocks with the `product_type_data` alias. In your case, [see the grouped product handle `PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml#L291):

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Grouped)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_grouped" name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.grouped.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
```

Comment: Could you please tell us Only what to do in situation instead of telling all the story ??

Comment: @PratikCJoshi -  I won't, because I don't know your story. Besides, what I present here is precisely what one needs to know to implement full product display behavior in a new custom theme. If you have a specific question about what is and isn't working in your case, you should ask a new question.